# Windows installation on laptop stutters

Tags: laptop, windows-server-2008-r2

My installation of Server 2008 R2 started stuttering suddenly (audio, mouse pointer, typing, scrolling, opening/running/closing programs, everything). I haven't made any hardware changes to it lately. I haven't installed any new software, haven't made any changes to system settings. And even though it stutters, there is no spike in cpu activity, and neither does the laptop seem to be unusually hot.

I also have an installation of Ubuntu 10.04 but it doesn't stutter (unless I play videos on vlc player).

Any ideas on what could be wrong and what I could check to find out (and fix)?

Comment: R2 is not intended as a laptop OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I should mention how I fixed the problem.

I went through services and stopped/disabled the ones that I knew I wasn't using. There had previously been an installation of [AppServ](http://www.appservnetwork.com/) that wasn't cleanly uninstalled, so the services for both Apache and MySQL were being "started", but they weren't really even there (they might have been the main cause). So I disabled them as well. My ISP uses static IP so I stopped the DHCP service as well.

Then I rebooted, and everything has been fine since, alhamdulillah.

Answer (score 0):

Have Windows/Microsoft Updates been put on the machine or are they set to run automatically as the Updates starting coming through a week yesterday from Microsoft.

If not it's possible you may have bad sectors on your Hard Drive or the head of the Hard Drive is not reading properly it maybe worth doing a system diagnosis on the machine using the manufacturer's system diagnostics tool.

Comment: Windows update notifies me whenever there is an update and I run it whenever convenient (I have a slow connection). I installed Server 2k8r2 on it myself (it's from dreamspark) so there is no diagnostic tool for it from the manufacturer (asus).